# Arquillian Container Payara Managed not able to start domain - ClassNotFoundException: DomainResource

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian, payara

I am not able to get my `arquillian` tests running properly with a local payara server. Starting my application without the tests and the same payara server works totally fine. I am getting the follow error:

> Sep 21, 2019 9:35:06 AM
>   fish.payara.arquillian.container.payara.clientutils.PayaraClientUtil
>   getResponseMap SCHWERWIEGEND: exit_code: FAILURE, message: An error
>   occurred while processing the request. Please see the server logs for
>   details. [status: SERVER_ERROR reason: Service Unavailable] Sep 21,
>   2019 9:35:06 AM
>   fish.payara.arquillian.container.payara.CommonPayaraManager start
>   SCHWERWIEGEND: Could not connect to DAS on: http://127.0.0.1:4848

I use this in my pom file:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>payara-managed</id>

        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>fish.payara.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-payara-server-managed</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This is my arquillian file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0"/>

    <container qualifier="payara">
        <configuration>
            <property name="glassFishHome">D:\Development\Tools\payara5</property>
            <property name="domain">domain1</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

My payara-web file:

```
<!DOCTYPE payara-web-app PUBLIC "-//Payara.fish//DTD Payara Server 4 Servlet 3.0//EN" "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/payara/Payara-Server-Documentation/master/schemas/payara-web-app_4.dtd">
<payara-web-app>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</payara-web-app>
```

My test file:

```
package com.denfri91.maka.persistence;

import com.denfri91.maka.common.entity.Saison;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SaisonRepositoryTest {
    @Inject
    SaisonRepository saisonRepository;

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClasses(Saison.class, SaisonRepository.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "payara-web.xml")
                .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void test_saisons_exist() {
        assertFalse(saisonRepository.queryAll().isEmpty());
    }
}
```

My persistence file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="MaKaPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/tvs_maka</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Some stack traces in the server.log:

```
[2019-09-21T10:06:17.177+0200] [Payara 5.193] [INFORMATION] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.notification.NotificationService] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1569053177177] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Payara Notification Service bootstrapped with configuration: NotificationExecutionOptions{enabled=true, notifierConfigurationExecutionOptionsList={LOG=LogNotifierConfigurationExecutionOptions{useSeparateLogFile=false} NotifierConfigurationExecutionOptions{notifierType=LOG, enabled=true, noisy=true}}}]]

[2019-09-21T10:06:17.220+0200] [Payara 5.193] [INFORMATION] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1569053163173] [timeMillis: 1569053177220] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network Listener JMS_PROXY_default_JMS_host started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]]]

[2019-09-21T10:06:17.365+0200] [Payara 5.193] [INFORMATION] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=149 _ThreadName=Thread-16] [timeMillis: 1569053177365] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0:8686/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:8686/jmxrmi]]

[2019-09-21T10:06:17.707+0200] [Payara 5.193] [SCHWERWIEGEND] [] [javax.enterprise.admin.rest] [tid: _ThreadID=158 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1569053177707] [levelValue: 1000] [[

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.generatedASM.DomainResource not found by org.glassfish.main.admin.rest-service [343]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1597)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestManagementResourceProvider.getResourceClasses(RestManagementResourceProvider.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.exposeContext(RestAdapter.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:175)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2019-09-21T10:06:17.735+0200] [Payara 5.193] [INFORMATION] [NCLS-REST-00003] [javax.enterprise.admin.rest] [tid: _ThreadID=158 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1569053177735] [levelValue: 800] [[
  An error occurred while processing the request. Please see the server logs for details.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Registered component class cannot be null.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.checkComponentClassNotNull(CommonConfig.java:562)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.register(CommonConfig.java:400)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.registerClasses(ResourceConfig.java:474)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:340)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.AbstractRestResourceProvider.getResourceConfig(AbstractRestResourceProvider.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestManagementResourceProvider.getResourceConfig(RestManagementResourceProvider.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.exposeContext(RestAdapter.java:323)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:175)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

Do you have any ideas what i am doing wrong? The jdbc connection is correctly configured, because like i mentioned without arquillian everything works fine.

Comment: `Please see the server logs for details`  Anything useful in there?

Comment: ive addded parts of the server log... it seems the url isnt correct, or?

Comment: What do you mean? The 0.0.0.0 URLs? That is OK, it means it listens on all available interfaces.  You do not have by any chance secure admin enabled (https)? Just asking because it is trying to connect to http.

Comment: What happens when you use "production" as domain in the arquillian file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed with Payara 5.193.1.
See release notes: https://docs.payara.fish/release-notes/release-notes-193.1.html

> [PAYARA-4131] - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.generatedASM.DomainResource not
>   found by org.glassfish.main.admin.rest-service

Here is the PR fixing it: https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/4224

Comment: Its been a while... had no time to retest it and answer you... I will give it a try with the new version. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @DennisF. Glad it worked. Maybe you could accept the answer then. :) Thanks